# Create element from input type='text' JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create DOM elements with info taken from input type text. To be more specific:
I want the user to be able to write a location and after he presses "Go!" button an element to be created with the text inserted and I also want to have a delete icon which when pressed to delete that insert.

I created a function in which I took the input value but I cannot create the 'del' button

If I create another `<img>` inside  using the same method, when I create the second entry it will put another `<img>` to the previous entry

```
 search_btn.click(function() {

    var place_reg = /^[a-z]+\d*[a-z]*(\s[a-z]+\d*[a-z]*)*?$/i;
    var search_value = search_box.val();
    var final_result = search_value.trim();

    if (place_reg.test(final_result)) {

        createDest(final_result);           

    } else {

        alert('Please insert a valid destination');
    }

    document.getElementById('search_box').value = "";
});

function toTitleCase(str) {

    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){ return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
 txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}

function createDest(value) {

    var destination_i_search = document.createElement("div");
    destination_i_search.innerHTML = toTitleCase(value);
    destination_i_search.setAttribute("class" , "place");       
    $("#dest").append(destination_i_search);            

}
```

Comment: The problem is in the code you are not showing. Please show the rest (an example of the HTML e.g. in a JSFiddle would be nice too) :)

Comment: You have this tagged jQuery, but are not using jQuery. The code will be shorter/simpler if you do, so is JQuery an option for you?

Comment: Yes I also use Jquery but I am not very used to it. I couldn't find what I needed in Jquery documentation

Comment: You need to provide a better example. e.g. I can't see where you are adding a delete button.

Comment: It is added the same way as the destination_i_search. It has as a parent the destination_i_search element. Var del= document.createElement ('img')

Comment: You need to either 1) attach the delete click handler to the new element *when you create it*, or 2) use a *delegated event handler* attached to a non-changing parent element. You do not provide the code that sets `search_btn`, or the HTML, so I cannot provide a specific example.

Comment: My problem is not the delete button. My problem is the creation of the entire element. The text is not a problem because it will be created under the class i specify. But if i want to create a child of this element it will be created to the previous one as well. So if o say grecia as the first destination everything it will be ok. But when i add the second destination another child will also be created to the first one. In a few hours i will post the code

Comment: Do you mean you want the new element to replace any previous one added? "it will be created to the previous one as well" does not make sense. Please explain clearly.

Comment: I mean that first destination will have 2 delete buttons. When i create the third one the first will have 3 buttons and the second 2 buttons and so on

Comment: No reason it should... but you are not showing that code anyway. Do you want one delete button per item added and each button just deletes that entry?

Comment: Yes i want one button per entry and the button deletes its corresponding entry

Comment: OK, that is what I finally guessed. Answer below. Let me know if you need more information or explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll take a better look when i get home and let u konw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to understand what you wish it to do, without a full example, but from comments you may want something like this:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6hn0n18/6/

I have converted it to use jQuery where appropriate.

```
var search_btn = $('#search');
var search_box = $('#searchbox');

search_btn.click(function () {
    var place_reg = /^[a-z]+\d*[a-z]*(\s[a-z]+\d*[a-z]*)*?$/i;
    var search_value = search_box.val() || "";
    var final_result = search_value.trim();
    if (place_reg.test(final_result)) {
        createDest(final_result);
    } else {
        alert('Please insert a valid destination');
    }
    search_box.val("");
});

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}

function createDest(value) {
    // use a div container
    var div = $("<div/>");
    div.html(toTitleCase(value));
    div.addClass("place");
    // If you want to replace the previous entry
    $("#dest").append(div);
    var del = $('<input class="delete" type="button" value="X"/>');
    $("#dest").append(del);
}

// This is a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    // Remove the previous div (if of class place)
    $(this).prev('.place').remove();
    // Remove the delete button too
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The key is to add a *delegated event handler* for the delete buttons. These work by listening for the specified event (`click` in this case) bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor. It *the* applies the jQuery selector. It *the* calls the function for any matching element *that caused the event*. The default ancestor is `document` if nothing closer to the changing content is available. In this case you could use  `#dest`

e.g.

```
$('#dest').on('click', '.delete', function(){
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want. I will provide th3 entire code when i get home